# Is there an easy way to upload the contents of an URL from the file chooser in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, upload

I want something similiar to the functionality on Windows computers.

You can just paste the URL in the open file window and Windows will automagically download the contents of the URL and select the file.

Is there a feature like this for Mac OS X?

If there isn't, what is the best alternative?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Open terminal, type curl and paste URL. You can build anything off that functionality. Maybe look in to an apple script to extend that?

Comment: @skub I want something faster

Answer (score 0):

The file picker in OS X is more limited than the one in Windows (where it's almost a full-blown file explorer itself).

The closest thing I think you can do is set up a service using the instructions here: [Quickly download files from URLs - Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/1157917/downloadurlservice.html)

From there, you could set up a Folder Action on the Downloads folder (or wherever you decide to send the files downloaded by your service to) to automatically open the new file downloaded by your service.